# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

i got this error when i logged in as guest, but when i logged in as admin , i didn't found it, any solutions?
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaLxr.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide code and context console doesn't show enough information

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the AntiCopy 1.8.2 Joomla Extension? I think this might be related to this...

I just installed it on one of my Joomla 3.6.2 website, setting restrictions on Guest and Public usergroups and get this error 3000+ times and keeps increasing. I disabled the plugin and reloaded the page, and no more errors. So it would appear that there is some issues with this plugin to disable right click, select and copy content.

It seems to add this code to the body tag: `onload="setInterval('window.clipboardData.clearData()',20)"` which seems to be the source of the error messages

Comment: yes , i installed anticopy. Thank you for your suggestion, i will try it,